# Raspberry Pi SSH connection broken - IP address changed

Tags: static-ip

When booting the Pi this morning the SSH connection was refused. An ifconfig revealed that the last digit of the IP address of the PI has changed. I adjusted the SSH configuration and ever since the connection works fine.

Why did the IP address change? How can I prevent it from changing?

UPDATE: eventually doing `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`, removing '`iface eth0 inet dhcp'` and adding these lines helped:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.6
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Have you assigned the Pi a static IP address or is it given one by DHCP?  Perhaps adding the contents of the Pi's /etc/network/interfaces file to your post would help.

Comment: Your router might support static-leases (or whatever they call it). That way you can set a mac address of your Pi, and link it to a fixed IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that you haven't set a static IP for your RPi. The most of modern routers use DHCP - you obtain automatic IP address.

I'm writing a little tutorial for my friends about RPi. How to set static IP address is [here](http://tutos.readthedocs.org/en/latest/source/RPi.html#network-configuration)

More about networking not only on RPi is just [few paragraphs higher](http://tutos.readthedocs.org/en/latest/source/RPi.html#little-networking)

Comment: Very helpful, cheers!